# After Proguard with Android，I got this error when open the App：java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

this is what happened,but I do not know what went wrong。Anyone could help me will be thankful。

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method c(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Landroid/util/Log; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.Log' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
    at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.isVMMultidexCapable(SourceFile:333)
    at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.<clinit>(SourceFile:78)
    at android.support.multidex.MultiDex.install(SourceFile)
    at android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication.attachBaseContext(SourceFile:39)
    at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:203)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1011)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:995)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:806)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5786)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6564)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1134)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Comment: You should add your app build.gradle file (or at least a part of it) and the proguard-rules.pro content. I suspect you are missing a line like this `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` in your release buildType